# non trivial solution of Homogenous equation

Tags: linear-algebra

i would like to recall  why is that   if

$A*x=0$

where $A$ is some   square matrix has non trivial solution if  matrix is singular?i was trying to  recall it,we can represent  $A*x=0$ as  for example in case of  three by three matrix  we have

$a(1,1)*x_1+a(1,2)*x_2+a(1,3)*x_3=0$

$a(2,1)*x_1+a(2,2)*x_2+a(2,3)*x_3=0$

$a(3,1)*x_1+a(3,2)*x_2+a(3,3)*x_3=0$

we can represent each equation as   dot product  of  each vector  $a$ and $x$,from which it is clear they are orthogonal to each other,let me know if i am wrong,does  determinant is zero means that all these  vectors  that are orthogonal  to $x$ vector,must be located on plane?as i know  determination of vectors are co planar is that  determinant of matrix  creates by  these vectors as a column elements  must be zero?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an $n$-dimensional space, Independence of vectors implies a lot. Let $\mathbf{a_1},\mathbf{a_2},\mathbf{a_3},\dots,\mathbf{a_n}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. The vectors are independent if and only if $\alpha_1\mathbf{a_1}+\alpha_2\mathbf{a_2}+\dots+\alpha_n\mathbf{a_n}=0$ has no non-zero solution to it and the only solution is $\alpha_i=0,\forall i=1,2,3,\dots,n$. Now the condition can be rephrased in several different ways:

1. The determinant of the Matrix $\mathbf{A}=\left[\mathbf{a_1}\space\mathbf{a_2}\space\dots\space\mathbf{a_n} \right]$ will be non-zero because the Row reduced Echelon form has all pivots as non-zeros.
2. Independence doesn't mean orthogonality. The vectors $\left[1 \space1\right]$ and $\left[1 \space 2\right]$ are independent but they are not orthogonal. On the other hand, $\left[1 \space1\right]$ and $\left[1 \space -1\right]$ are independent and orthogonal. It can be proven that Orthogonality implies independence.
3. The equation $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ will have no non-trivial solution because of point 1; the value of $x_1, x_2,\dots,x_n$ will automatically equate to zero since there are no free-variables. All of them become Pivot variables.
4. For the 3-dimensional case as posed in your question, it means that the vectors $\mathbf{a_1},\mathbf{a_2},\mathbf{a_3}$ cannot be coplanar for the equation to hold a non-zero solution. If they are coplanar, it means that they are "linearly" dependent.

Comment: so why  singular  matrix has non zero solution?

Comment: Because you can assign non-zeros to free variables. If you tried to reduce a singular matrix to its Row-reduced Echelon form, you'll see that at least one of the rows will be all zeros, which means the variables corresponding to zero pivots can be any value.